# ANR due to DataBindingUtil.inflate()

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-anr-dialog

In my app, I am observing ANRs in Activities and Fragments due to DataBindingUtil.inflate(). Please suggest what could be the reason and if there is any solution for it.
I am just calling DataBindingUtil.inflate() in onCreate()/onCreateView(), and the layouts are also not very nested.

**Sample Trace 1**

```
main (runnable): tid=1 systid=2837
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:183)
   at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:8584)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:2902)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1934)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:486)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
   at com.android.tools.r8.GeneratedOutlineSupport.outline13(GeneratedOutlineSupport.java)
   at com.xyz.pqr.ui.account.fragment.AccountFragment.onCreateView(AccountFragment.java)
```

**Sample Trace 2**

```
main (native): tid=1 systid=31028
#00 pc 0x54678 libc.so 
#01 pc 0x130ceb libart.so 
#02 pc 0x4cd44b libart.so 
#03 pc 0x4cd2d1 libart.so 
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenXmlAsset(AssetManager.java)
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:1117)
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1336)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2441)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2417)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1261)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1226)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1134)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1141)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
   at com.xyz.pqr.ui.homeactivity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:228)
```

Comment: Can u add what gradle plugin version `com.android.tools.build:gradle` you were using when u got this ANR ? Also were u able to fix this ANR by any chance ?